# .htaccess doesn't redirect to the e-commerce subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My server structure is:

```
folder/
..
..
publicl_html/ ( Hehe is my project )
..
..
```

In `public_html` is my corporative site and there is also a folder which name is `store`. In this folder is the e-commerce part. The domain for this folder should be `mysite.com/store/`. I have a `.htaccess` file in the corporative part which redirects to the `store` prat :

```
#AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#Options +FollowSymLinks
#IndexIgnore */*
#RewriteEngine on


# Make the backend accessible via url: http://site/admin
#RewriteRule ^admin$ $admin.php [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
#RewriteRule . index.php


#RewriteRule ^static - [L]


# prevent directory listings
#Options -Indexes
# follow symbolic links
#Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(store)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^(admin)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

This line `RewriteRule ^(store)($|/) - [L]`. It is redirecting because i test it with just an `index.php` before uploading the whole project. But now i got `404`error again ( the error page from the corporative site `mysite.com`).
This is the `.htaccess` in the `public_html/store/ ( mysite.com/store/ )` folder :

```
#AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#Options +FollowSymLinks
#IndexIgnore */*
#RewriteEngine on


# Make the backend accessible via url: http://site/admin
#RewriteRule ^admin$ $admin.php [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
#RewriteRule . index.php


#RewriteRule ^static - [L]


# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^(admin)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

Guess the problem is in the second `.htaccess` but i am not familiar with those redirects and seems that I will not handle it without your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `mysite.bg/store/` but now I`ve changed the `.htaccess` of the `store` directory to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mystore.com/store/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mystore.com/store/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mystore.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` and i got `This page don't work`.

Comment: `mystore.com/store` is just alias for my site because it seems that there is real domain like this one :D

Comment: No. Again `This page not found`.

Comment: Do you have `index.php` inside `store` directory?

Comment: In the store directory - No. Only in `frontend/web/index.php`. The MVC is Yii2 if that matters somehow.